# Convert hours and minutes into minutes

Tags: r, time

I have a vector of event times in the form of hours, minutes, and seconds. Now I wish to convert all of these times into minutes. For example, 01:02:18 would become 62 minutes.

My data:

```
times
"01:02:18" "01:47:37" "01:18:48" "01:32:54" "01:09:41" "01:50:30"
```

Code I tried but it did not work:

```
time = format(strptime(matchtime,"%H:%M:%S"),'%M')
```

Guessing there is something that could be done by adding the hours and minutes. However, I am unsure on how to do that as well.

Comment: took the liberty of assuming that you really meant "minutes" and not ["minuets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuet) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to extract the minutes and hours

```
library(lubridate)
v1 <- hms(times)
v1@hour * 60 + v1@minute
[1]  62 107  78  92  69 110
```

Or to include the seconds as well

```
period_to_seconds(hms(times))/60
[1]  62.30000 107.61667  78.80000  92.90000  69.68333 110.50000
```

Answer (score 3):

in base R:

```
difftime(strptime(matchtime,"%T"), strptime('0:0:0','%T'), units = 'min')
Time differences in mins
[1]  62.30000 107.61667  78.80000  92.90000  69.68333 110.50000
```

same as:

```
as.numeric(strptime(matchtime,"%T") - strptime('0:0:0', "%T"),'mins')
[1]  62.30000 107.61667  78.80000  92.90000  69.68333 110.50000
```

### Edit

using data.table:

```
as.numeric(data.table::as.ITime(matchtime))/60
[1]  62.30000 107.61667  78.80000  92.90000  69.68333 110.50000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as.difftime` and set the units to `mins`.

```
as.difftime(times, units = "mins")
#Time differences in mins
#[1]  62.30000 107.61667  78.80000  92.90000  69.68333 110.50000
```

To ignore the seconds use `floor`.

```
floor(as.difftime(times, units = "mins"))
#Time differences in mins
#[1]  62 107  78  92  69 110
```

Data

```
times <- c("01:02:18", "01:47:37", "01:18:48", "01:32:54", "01:09:41", "01:50:30")
```